# TeXShop, BibDesk, URLs not shown and extra citation numbers?

Tags: texshop, back-referencing, bibdesk

I am using TeXShop and BibDesk on Mac and even though I add "webpage" entries to BibDesk, they don't show up in TeXShop.[image: added entry]

[image: fail]

Also, I get these extra citation numbers at the end of my document:
[image: why]

when I don't have anything after the references.

[image]

What is wrong? I have the correct packages, I think:

[image]

EDIT: I was able to get rid of the extra reference numbers by adding a `\nocite{*}` and deleting the references.

FME:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{PANs}

\end{document}
```

and in the PANs.bib file, I have

```
@article{nfcforum,
    Author = {NFC Forum},
    Date-Added = {2014-05-05 12:12:03 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-05-05 13:39:56 +0000},
    Lastchecked = {5 May 2014},
    Title = {What is NFC?},
    Url = {http://nfc-forum.org/what-is-nfc/},
    Urldate = {5 May 2014},
    Year = {2014}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/splncs.bst, `splncs` does not provide support for a `url` key, so it is silently ignored.

You may want to add the URL in a note field (using `\url{URL}`, remember to load the `url` package).

Comment: I tried, but urls still do not show.

Comment: Would you please provide a full minimal example.

Comment: I have edited the original post.

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? I do not get any references in `[...]`, you I'm geussing, you are not telling us the whole truth. BTW: the `splncs03.bst`, does support the `url` key.